# How to set a conditional breakpoint on specific register value in OllyDbg?

Tags: debuggers, ollydbg

I want to set a conditional breakpoint if the register is an unicode like `'m'` or `'a'` or `'2'` using ollydbg.

How can i do that ?

I have the latest version of Ollydbg '2.01'. `OllyStepNSearch` plugin is used for this case but it is not compatible with the above version of Olly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What keeps you from using the Ollydbg version where this plugin is compatible?

Comment: @justsome i have tried the old version with that plugin and is not working either !

Comment: OllyDbg has conditional breakpoint capabilities, have you tried that first?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you use OllyDBG version 1.10 (non-plugin) or Other edition like odbgSND.

You can use Conditional BP with below grammar:

```
UNICODE [EAX]=="HamiD a.k.a AHA"
```

OllyDbg treats `EAX` as a pointer to UNICODE string, converts it to ASCII and compares with text constant. If you want the Unicode value of the register must be written as the following conditions:

```
EAX == 75007500
```

This condition is triggered if the value of `EAX` equal `uu` Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Check these out :

http://www.openrce.org/forums/posts/634

http://www.woodmann.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-8043.html

And here is two conditions I recently used in Olly:

```
([UNICODE[esp+10]] !="BAR") && ([UNICODE[esp]] =="FOO")
[[STRING[esp+8]] =="FOO"] && [[STRING[esp+4]] !="BAR"]
```