# OllyDbg Break when memory equals value

Tags: ollydbg

I'm wanting to have olly run a program and break when a particular memory location equals a given value. For instance, if I could have it run until the value at address 0xFB2D0024 == 0xE9, and then break immediately when that assignment occurs. Please let me know if this is possible!

The "conditional" breaks I found in [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2763/how-to-set-a-conditional-breakpoint-on-specific-register-value-in-ollydbg) did not work, or rather when I right clicked -> breakpoint -> Conditional, and then entered a condition, the program simply broke at the instruction where I right-clicked, regardless of the condition, and not when the condition occurred.

The closest I can get is right clicking on a particular memory value (in the memory dump) -> breakpoint -> Memory, on write, but this breaks every time a change is made, and not when a specific value is set. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write script for ODbgScript plugin,

It might look like this:

```
VAR pDest
VAR Val

mov pDest, FB2D0024 // dest address
mov Val, E9 // val to look for

bpwm pDest, 4 // set bp on writing DWORD (4bytes) value.
__lbl_loop:
erun
cmp [pDest], Val
jne __lbl_loop
bpmc
LOG "Catched ^(._.^)"
```

Comment: Thank you. This does what I'm looking for, unfortunately I've now realized that setting a breakpoint on write, and then checking the value it writes is a bit too slow (the memory value is written to hundreds of times a second). Time to move on to a workaround (not involving this memory value).